# Mesh sculpt symmetry not working? it doesn’t respect the mesh local direction

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[image]i want the sculpt symmetry to face the direction the face is at but its following some other corral perhaps the global x/y/z directions?

i already messed around with the mesh symmetry settings and nothing works.

and i tried
the “apply all transforms” too

–i need it on this angle because the reference head is facing at a certain angle.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/